# General formula for finding $\limsup A_n,\liminf A_n$, where $A_n$ is a sequence of sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I would like to know if there is a general formula, and if so, what it is, for finding the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of a sequence of sets $A_n$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

I know the following examples:

**(1)**

for $A_n=(0,a_n], (a_1,a_2)=(10,200)$, $a_n=1+1/n$ for $n$ odd and $a_n=5-1/n$ for $n$ even, and $n\geq 3$,

$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n = 5$, $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n = 1$, $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n = (0,5)$, $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n = (0,1]$.

**(2)**

for $A_n=[0,a_n), (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)=(10,100,1000,10000)$, $a_{2n+1}=2-1/(2n+1)$ for $n\geq2$ and $a_{2n}=4+1/(2n)$ for $n\geq4$,

$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n = 4$, $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n = 2$, $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n = [0,4]$, $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n = [0,2)$.

**(3)**

for $A_n=(0,a_n], (a_1,a_2)=(50,20)$, $a_{3n}=1+1/(3n), a_{3n+1}=1+1/(3n+1), a_{3n+2}=3-1/(3n+2)$ for $n\geq1$,

$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n = 3$, $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n = 1$, $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n = (0,3)$, $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n = (0,1)$.

**Is there a general formula describing $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n$ and $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n$ with the open/closed interval notation, for an arbitrarily defined $\{a_n\}$?**

Thanks for any help!